# Getting funny output for insertion sort

Tags: c++, insertion-sort

I'm trying to implement insertion sort. My logic may be wrong because I was unable to complete my code due to some error.
I want help with values changing absurdly while executing. Also, there is a similar repeating element question but it is in python and it went over my head. so, please don't mark it duplicate.

As you can see I have initialized a temporary variable index, why you ask? because the value of **N** is changing during run time.
secondly, Value is getting repeated when sorting is taking place.
I'm using codeblocks 17.2.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<utility>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
  cin.tie(0);

  int arr[100];
  int N,index;
  cin>>N;

  for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
  {
     cin>>arr[i];
  }
  index=N;                   // using temperory variable
  for(int l=0;l<index;l++)
  {
    for(int j=l+1;j>=0;j--)
    {

        if(l==index-1 || j==0)    //Working fine now 
            break;

        if(arr[j]<arr[j-1])
        {

          swap(arr[j],arr[j-1]);
        }


    }
    cout<<N<<endl;             //value of n is changing but why
    for(int k=0;k<index;k++)
    {

        cout<<arr[k]<<" ";   //value of array is also coming wrong
    }
    cout<<"\n";

  }

 return 0;
}
```

**N=7**
and elements of the array to be

> 7 8 5 2 4 6 3

output is

> 7              //these are the values of N which is changing
>
> 7 8 5 2 4 6 3
>
> 5
>
> 7 7 8 2 4 6 3
>
> 2
>
> 5 7 7 8 4 6 3
>
> 2
>
> 4 5 7 7 8 6 3
>
> 2
>
> 4 5 6 7 7 8 3
>
> 2
>
> 3 4 5 6 7 7 8
>
> 0
>
> 2 3 4 5 6 7 7

Comment: Check your loop bounds and your array accesses. They don't match up. Hint: accessing out of bounds array indices or reading uninitialized variables causes [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub), which can change the value of unrelated variables.

Comment: "because the value of N is changing during run time in the third loop." - since clearly you've written no such code that explicitly did this, perhaps you should pursue *why* that is happening rather than tossing in `index` (which clearly shouldn't be necessary). Hint: You're *likely* breaching array boundaries in your algorithm. I suggest your review any of the *thousands* of known-proper insertion-sort implementations via google-fu to see where the wheels fell off this wagon. Or, a dozen minutes in a line-by-line debug session may go a long way.

Comment: @AlexanderZhang Ok, my nested **for** was trying to access **arr[N]** which doesn't really exist. So, I introduced a condition which will stop it from doing the above still getting the same output. By the way, if I'm trying to access out of bound array indices why is it affecting variable N?

Comment: @WhozCraig Ok, my nested **for** was trying to access **arr[N]** which doesn't really exist. So, I introduced a condition which will stop it from doing the above still getting the same output. By the way, if I'm trying to access out of bound array indices why is it affecting variable N?

Comment: You have another boundary issue when `j == 0`.

Comment: @eras'q `N` is affected because it is stored next to the array in memory.

Comment: @molbdnilo Thank you, it's working now. **But N is stored next to the array in the memory**. Doesn't the memory allocations is supposed to be random? And what I was doing previously was affecting the **N** next to array right?

Comment: If you wanted to debug this yourself (or remember this for future situations which are similar), `g++ -g -fsanitize=address` gave a fairly specific error message pointing to where things are going wrong.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Can you please provide me with a link of the above.

Comment: @eras'q Umm, not sure what you're looking for...  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html is the gcc documentation page describing `-fsanitize=address` and that further links to https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer

Comment: Anything can happen with undefined behavior. What makes you think the positions of stuff in memory, especially things on the stack are always random? They're random in the sense that you shouldn't rely on them being a specific way, but they're not random like a dice roll. And we aren't even taking into account the crazy optimizing powers of modern compilers which can make all sorts of weird stuff happen when you invoke UB. In this case, it appears that `N` was stored right before `arr` and it changed when you modified `arr[-1]`.

Comment: @eras'q To answer your question why N memory was allocated after the array, it is allocated in stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check for boundary condition and when non-existing array index is accessed it will give undefined behavior. In this case, it appears that N was stored right before arr and it changed when you modified arr[-1].